# XULSchool make: *** No rule to make target '../bin/build', needed by 'install'. Stop

Tags: makefile, firefox-addon

I'm working through the xulschool tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Setting_Up_a_Development_Environment)

Everything's going pretty well so far but I'm having trouble with the makefile they included. "make" works fine but "make install" throws the error:

```
"make: *** No rule to make target '../bin/build', needed by 'install'.  Stop."
```

I have never used make before but it looks like it wants some extra parameters that are not mentioned anywhere in the tutorial. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

contents of the makefile:

```
# The name of the extension.
    extension_name := xulschoolhello

# The UUID of the extension.
extension_uuid := helloworld@xulschool.com

# The name of the profile dir where the extension can be installed.
profile_dir := XULSchool

# The zip application to be used.
ZIP := zip

# The target location of the build and build files.
bin_dir := ../bin

# The target XPI file.
xpi_file := $(bin_dir)/$(extension_name)2.xpi

# The type of operating system this make command is running on.
os_type := $(patsubst darwin%,darwin,$(shell echo $(OSTYPE)))

# The location of the extension profile.
ifeq ($(os_type), darwin)
  profile_location := \
    ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/$(profile_dir)/extensions/\{$(extension_uuid)\}
else
  ifeq ($(os_type), linux-gnu)
    profile_location := \
      ~/.mozilla/firefox/$(profile_dir)/extensions/\{$(extension_uuid)\}
  else
    profile_location := \
      "$(subst \,\\,$(APPDATA))\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\$(profile_dir)\\extensions\\{$(extension_uuid)}"
  endif
endif

# The temporary location where the extension tree will be copied and built.
build_dir := $(bin_dir)/build

# This builds the extension XPI file.
.PHONY: all
all: $(xpi_file)
    @echo
    @echo "Build finished successfully."
    @echo

# This cleans all temporary files and directories created by 'make'.
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf $(build_dir)
    @rm -f $(xpi_file)
    @echo "Cleanup is done."

# The sources for the XPI file.
xpi_built := install.rdf \
             chrome.manifest \
             $(wildcard content/*.js) \
             $(wildcard content/*.xul) \
             $(wildcard content/*.xml) \
             $(wildcard content/*.css) \
             $(wildcard skin/*.css) \
             $(wildcard skin/*.png) \
             $(wildcard locale/*/*.dtd) \
             $(wildcard locale/*/*.properties)

# This builds everything except for the actual XPI, and then it copies it to the
# specified profile directory, allowing a quick update that requires no install.
.PHONY: install
install: $(build_dir) $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder: $(profile_location)"
    @cp -Rf $(build_dir)/* $(profile_location)
    @echo "Installing in profile folder. Done!"
    @echo


$(xpi_file): $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Creating XPI file."
    @$(ZIP) $(xpi_file) $(xpi_built)
    @echo "Creating XPI file. Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and ran into the problem, but I managed to get it working by manually creating the following folder (on OSX):

`~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xulschool-dev/extensions/{helloworld@xulschool.com}`

However, I found out later that the folder `xulschool-dev` is created by setting up a new Firefox profile with that exact name.

Comment: Hm, I got the same problem (win7 x64) but creating the profile and so creating the directory didn't solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on my Mac by assigning:

```
profile_location := \
~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/$(profile_dir)/extensions/\{$(extension_uuid)\}
```

Because for some reason the `else` (line 26) statement is executed on Mac.

Prior to that `$(profile_dir)` needs to be created. How to create it is explained [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

Also:

```
build_dir := $(bin_dir)
```

instead of

```
build_dir := $(bin_dir)/build
```

right after they are initiated.

But the command `make clean` will get broken, to fix it:

```
@rm -rf $(build_dir)/bin
```

instead of:

```
@rm -rf $(build_dir)
```

The final result is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bhjbfc0t/1/